# How can I make package-lock, integrity SHAs, and locally built modules as tgz all work together?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Consider the following scenario:

We have some modules that we install as tgz.

In package.json, they are referred to as:

```
"somePackage": "file:../modules/somePackage.tgz",
```

We'd like to use package-lock, and so we create package-lock files.

The package-lock file has:

```
 "node_modules/somePackage": {
      "version": "1.0.97",
      "resolved": "file:../modules/somePackage.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-PXp1Q75feN1P+PHhqZmPF/J/5q5oVnALOVtdDq69Bn29sqFdwHkNL1k4DjOBYbh1C8y8beETOc7T77hMUhrWmQ==",
      "dev": true,
```

The problem has to do with the integrity checksum. When rebuilding the package, and then running `npm install`, it fails integrity check.

I am not sure what the best way to go about this would be. Ultimately it would be nice to have a way to ignore checksum for tarballs like that, but I am not sure there is a way.

Currently using Npm 7 and Node 14.

Answer (score 0):

Though I disagree with the fact that npm checks integrity checksum of locally built tarballs, the real issue is that locally you shouldn't need to build tarballs. Local builds should rely on [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces).

The example in my question should be setup like this:

1. Remove `"somePackage": "file:../modules/somePackage.tgz",`
2. Setup `workspaces` section that looks like this:

```
"workspaces" : [
  "../modules/somePackage"
]
```